# Proper derivation of dz[1] expression for backpropagation algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

For backpropagation algorithm, is it true to have weight, $w$ transposed in the expression of $dz^{[1]} = w^{[2]T}dz^{[2]} * g^{[1]'}(z^{[1]}) $ ? Could anyone show me why $w^{[2]T}$ instead of just $w$ ?

I have read other articles, but the transposed dimension of $w$ is ignored when chain derivation is applied.

Screenshot from [Andrew Ng deeplearning coursera course video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks-deep-learning/lecture/6dDj7/backpropagation-intuition-optional):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For backpropagation algorithm, is it true to have weight, $w$ transposed in the expression of $dz^{[1]} = w^{[2]T}dz^{[2]} * g^{[1]'}(z^{[1]}) $ ?

Yes it is correct. You can show it is with some different arguments:

### Checking correct dimensions

Although this is not a robust theoretical argument, checking dimensions is actually what I do in practice when I am confused when implementing NNs.

Here's the rough logic of a dimension check on the equation in your question:

- $W^{[2]}$ is a $n^{[2]} \times n^{[1]}$ matrix for the forward propagation to work.
- $dz^{[2]}$ is a $n^{[2]} \times 1$ column vector (because it is the gradient of cost function with respect to $z^{[2]}$, so it has to have the same dimension as it)
- $dz^{[1]}$ is a $n^{[1]} \times 1$ column vector
- It is $dz^{[2]}$ that is being multiplied - so the multiplying matrix must be $\text{something} \times n^{[2]}$.
- The output needs to be same dimensions as $dz^{[1]}$ - so the matrix must also be $n^{[1]} \times \text{something}$.
- That means the multiplying matrix must have dimensions $n^{[1]} \times n^{[2]}$ - which $W^{[2]T}$ has (and no other component of the network could match)

### Theory from item-by-item calculation, converted to matrix math

But *why* is it $W^{[2]T}$ and not some other matrix with the desired dimensions? For that we need to go back to the chain rule. Note that the expression you have written is actually *two* steps of the chain rule combined - first we derive $da^{[1]}$ from $dz^{[2]}$, then we derive $dz^{[1]}$ from $da^{[1]}$. It is that first step that introduces terms from $W^{[2]}$, so I will just show that. Also, [deriving this directly using matrix notation is more complex](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18279/deriving-backpropagation-equations-natively-in-tensor-form), so we'll just drop into using the index values, and use the "official" partial derivative notation.

To calculate $da^{[1]}$ for a specific $i^{th}$ neuron, you have to sum over the gradients $dz^{[2]}$ for all the neurons it links to:

$$ \frac{\partial J}{\partial a_i^{[1]}} = \sum_j \frac{\partial J}{\partial z_j^{[2]}} \frac{\partial z_j^{[2]}}{\partial a_i^{[1]}} = \sum_j \frac{\partial J}{\partial z_j^{[2]}} W_{ij}^{[2]} $$

Doing this for each $i$ value in turn gets your the full $da^{[1]}$ vector.

Compare this to how the forward propagation works in the same network using the same notation and indexing:

$$z^{[2]}_j = b^{[2]}_j + \sum_i W_{ij}^{[2]} a_i^{[1]}$$

And you can see that the index used to drive the sum is different between forward and backward calculations:

- When we write $W^{[2]}_{ij}$, then $i$ is index of matrix row, $j$ is index of matrix column from $W^{[2]}$.
- When multiplying forward, we sum over $i$, i.e. each row of $W^{[2]}$ multiplied by each matching element of $a^{[1]}$, and this is summed up.
- When you look at the gradient, you can see the equivalent sum is over $j$.
- To turn that gradient calculation into a normal matrix multiply (just so the matrix notation works, and you don't have to write out the sum) you have to swap rows and columns - which is what a transpose is.

This is partly a definitions and notation issue. We could define a different kind of matrix multiply that worked with sums column-by-column. But this is not usually done, because multiplying by the transpose does the same thing.

Comment: "Summing over columns at a time instead of rows when performing the multiplications is the same operation as transposing the matrix and summing over rows (i.e. a standard matrix multiply)."

>> I do not understand this sentence.

Comment: @kevin: I'll try to re-phrase it in the answer. Basically $i$ is index of matrix row, $j$ is index of matrix column from $W$. When multiplying forward, we sum over rows of $W$ multiplied by each matching element of $a$. When you look at the gradient, you can see the sum is over $j$. To turn that gradient calculation into a normal matrix multiply you have to swap rows and columns - which is what a transpose it.

Comment: Sorry for repeating my comments over and over again. I am a bit confused on "normal matrix multiply" for the gradient calculation

Comment: @kevin: By "normal" I mean there is only one kind of "official" matrix multiply defined, which I show in detail in the sum version of the forward propagation. The backpropation gradient calculation works using a sum over the other index, so it is not a multiplication by $W$ (because that would sum over $i$). Instead it can be represented by a multiplication by $W^T$

Comment: Just one additional comment: it does not seem to be similar case  for $dw^{[2]} = dz^{[2]} a^{[1]T}$ ?

Comment: @kevin: It is similar, but it is a different step in backprop and in this case you are building a *matrix* of gradients, not a vector. You can show it is correct dimensionally and using the item-by-item theory in a very similar way to this answer. But that would double the size of the answer here. I suggest you give it a try yourself to see if you have truly absorbed the answer . . .

Comment: OK. Sorry for making the comments block large.  I am still stucked with $ a_{ij}^{[1]} $  


$$ \frac{\partial J}{\partial w_i^{[2]}} = \sum_j \frac{\partial J}{\partial z_j^{[2]}} \frac{\partial z_j^{[2]}}{\partial w_i^{[2]}} = \sum_j \frac{\partial J}{\partial z_j^{[2]}} a_{ij}^{[1]} $$

Comment: Your expression is not correct. Each item in the weights matrix is indexed by $i$ and $j$ so you want $\frac{\partial J}{\partial W^{[2]}_{ij}}$. Also, there is no sum over multiple connections here, each $W_{ij}$ only connects one $a$ to one $z$, and influences the gradient of the loss function once. $a_{ij}$ does not exist, $a$ is a vector and has only one indexed dimension. The correct equation is in the course materials

Comment: $dz^{[1]} = \frac{dl}{dz2} \cdot \frac{dz2}{dz1}$ Right? If that is the case then it should only be: $dz^{[1]}=(w^{[2]})^Tdz^{[2]}$